# Laravel 5.8: Auto refresh div becomes messy and laggy using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have this website that has comment section in every news. I want to update the div every x seconds using a ajax function. But when I put the ajax code in my scripts, the div becomes messy and my site becomes lag and there are so many errors in the console. Anybody has an idea about this? Here are my outputs:

Before I implemented the code : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHKJF.jpg
After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE7Dj.jpg

shownews.blade.php

```
Comments area

     <h4 class="comments-title" > <span class="fas fa-comment-alt"></span>
                    {{$news->comments()->count()}}
                    Comments</h4>
                  <div class="row" >
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 400px;
                      width: 400px; " id="commentarea" >

                          @foreach($news->comments as $comment)
                            <div class="comment" style="background-color: #f6efef;" >
                          <div class="author-info">
                              <img src={{"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($comment->email))) . "?s=50&d=retro" }} class="author-image" id="image">

                              <div class="author-name">
                                   <h4>{{$comment->name}} </h4>
                                   <p class="author-time"> {{  date('jS F, Y - g:iA' ,strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</p>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                            <div class="comment-content">
                                    {{$comment->comment}}
                            </div>
                            </div>
                          @endforeach
                      </div>
                  </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
             setInterval(function() {
                $('#commentarea').load('{{ action('NewsController@showNews', ['news' => $news->id]) }}');
             }, 5000);
            });
           </script>
```

NewsController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\News;
use Validator;
use Image;
use View;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
// use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class NewsController extends Controller
{

//Shownews method. This is where the individual news is shown with its comments.

    public function showNews($id)
    {

        $all = DB::table('news')->get();
        $news = News::find($id);
        return View::make('coin.shownews', compact('news','all'));
    }
}
```

CommentsController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Comment;
use App\News;
use App\Graph;
use Validator;
use Session;


class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, $news_id)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'name'=> 'required | max:255',
            'email'=> 'required| email | max:255',
            'comment'=> 'required | min:5'
        ));

        $news = News::find($news_id);

        $comment = new Comment();

        $comment->name = $request->name;
        $comment->email = $request->email;
        $comment->comment = $request->comment;
        $comment->approved = true;
        $comment->news()->associate($news);

        $comment->save();


        // return $comment->toJson();

        return redirect()->route('article', [$news->id]);
}
```

Comment: You want to do a real time comment?

Comment: yes sir @Jovs. Do you  have some better solution about it? Im new in laravel btw.

Comment: I posted my idea. You can try it if it works

Comment: okay sir. thanks. Ill try it

Comment: Let me see your route setting

Comment: My route for the individual news

   
`Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']], function(){
    Route::get('/article/{id}', 'NewsController@showNews')->name('article');

});`

Route for comments in each news `Route::get('commentData/{id}/comment', 'NewsController@commentData');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why its behave like this because you're loading the whole web page when you call your view. So you need to separate it and use ajax to call the data you can use `@include` in view.

```
Comments area

 <h4 class="comments-title" > <span class="fas fa-comment-alt"></span>
                {{$news->comments()->count()}}
                Comments</h4>
              <div class="row" >
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 400px;
                  width: 400px; " id="commentarea" >
                  @include('table_data')
                  </div>
              </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
         setInterval(function() {
           var page = window.location.href;
           $.ajax({
           url: page+'/table,
           success:function(data)
           {
            $('#commentarea').html(data);
           }
           });
         }, 5000);
       });
           </script>
```

Create the include blade then put the needed element of commentarea
**table_data.blade.php**

```
                      @foreach($news->comments as $comment)
                        <div class="comment" style="background-color: #f6efef;" >
                         <div class="author-info">
                          <img src={{"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5(strtolower(trim($comment->email))) . "?s=50&d=retro" }} class="author-image" id="image">

                          <div class="author-name">
                               <h4>{{$comment->name}} </h4>
                        <p class="author-time"> {{  date('jS F, Y - g:iA' ,strtotime($comment->created_at)) }}</p>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                                {{$comment->comment}}
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      @endforeach
```

Of course you need to have another route for it and another function in controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\News;
use Validator;
use Image;
use View;
use Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
// use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class NewsController extends Controller
{

//Shownews method. This is where the individual news is shown with its comments.



 public function showNews($id)
    {
        $new = News::find($id);
        return view('coin.shownews')->with('new', $new);
    }
 public function commentData($id);
    {
        $all = DB::table('news')->get();
        $news = News::find($id);
        return view('table_data', compact('news', 'all'))->render();
    }
}
```

then add the route on
**web.php**

```
`Route::get('article/{id}/commentData', 'NewsController@commentData')`;
//you must change the name of the route base on your url just add the /table. Route can't be the same so you need to add that
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I followed your code sir but it gets me an error `jquery.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/undefined/comment 500 (Internal Server Error)`. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you on view news that gives an id? what's your url when you're on that web page

Comment: how can i post my codes? I want to show you what I have modified

Comment: Yes sir, Im in the view that has an news id.but if i try the url. 

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/commentData/5/comment` the comments will show. I added a route
 `Route::get('commentData/{id}/comment', 'NewsController@commentData');`

Comment: Also the function `showNews` that you modified in my controller didint work for me. So i didint modified it, I only added the `tableData` function you created.

Comment: I think the problem is in the ajax url? Im not good with ajax

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to put the news there. It's not in ajax its the url page in javascript. try to `alert(page);` after the var page in javascript. and tell me the result

Comment: it says `undefined` sir

Comment: change the var page to `var page = window.location.href;`

Comment: I got an error in the console sir. `GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/5/commentData 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: change this route `Route::get('commentData/{id}/comment', 'NewsController@commentData');` to `Route::get('article/{id}/commentData', 'NewsController@commentData');`

Comment: the url in your ajax and your route should be same. That's why its not found because they're not same just change the route that I said and everything should be fine

Comment: Thankyou sir. It worked for me. I know it is a bad practice so use `setInterval` method because it causes a strain in the server. But I think I should use this for now? or I will find a better solution asap?

Comment: Can you please edit your answer so that I can put a check on it

Comment: Usually most of the website with real time function use a firebase database because that's what the real-time database right now. Using ajax will always call a network inside of it. Every interval there's a new network that called and that's your ajax. Just observe it and if you think its affecting so big in the performance then learn how to use firebase. If not then there's no problem

Comment: someone said that I can use websockets but I had a hard time understanding it thats why I used the worst method hahahha. Sorry im just a newbie

Comment: Its okay I don't know how to use that too hahaha. We can learn everyday so if you have time you can study that and use it if you know how to use it. For now use that as your option.

Comment: Here to thanks! Btw why we need to use '@include'. If you don't use it you dont need to add same compact variables in the first function too. And a little sintax error on right of   `url: page+'/table,` to `url: page+'/table',`